# How to mark multiple products as favorit using SESSION

Tags: php, session

So what am I missing here? I'm trying to create a "favorites" function on my webpage. Visitors can see different product pages and select one product as favorite. On top of the page is an image. When the visitor clicks this image, a page is loaded with this line of code:

```
<?php 
session_start();

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

define("PRODUCTNAME", 1);
define("inURL", 1);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
if (isset($_POST['productname']))
{
  AddToCart();
}
} 


function AddToCart()
{
$cart = isset($_SESSION['cart']) ? $_SESSION['cart'] : '';
$itemcount = isset($_SESSION['itemcount']) ? $_SESSION['itemcount'] : 0;
$event = $_POST['productname'];
$savelink = $_POST['url'];

$cart[PRODUCTNAME][$itemcount] = array('eventnaam' => $event, 'savelink' => $savelink, 'favSRC' => 'favJA');
$itemcount = $itemcount + 1;

$_SESSION['cart'] = $cart;
$_SESSION['itemcount'] = $itemcount;
header('Location: ' . $_POST['url']);
exit;
} 
?>
```

This code creates different sessionvalues, because on the product page I need some things displayed.

On top of the product page there is the title. Next to the title a star is displayed (an image with `src=favNEE.png`, a star without color). At the right side on the page, in another `div` a list of marked products is displayed. This text (the productname) can be clicked so the visitor will go to the productpage again. The code of the product page:

```
<?php 
session_start();

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

define("PRODUCTNAME", 1);

$cart = isset($_SESSION['cart']) ? $_SESSION['cart'] : '';
$itemcount = isset($_SESSION['itemcount']) ? $_SESSION['itemcount'] : 0;
$strHTML = "";

if ($itemcount == 0)
{
$strHTML = "<font class='bewaardeItems'>U heeft nog geen evenementen aangeklikt.    </font>";
$imageSRC = 'favNEE';
}
else
{
$strHTML = "<div style=\"overflow:auto; height=358px;\">"."\n";
$strHTML .= "<table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"3\" cellspacing=\"2\"   width=\"100%\">"."\n";

for ($i=0; $i<$itemcount; $i++)
{
  $strHTML .= "<tr>"."\n";
  $strHTML .= "<td><a href='".$cart[PRODUCTNAME][$i]['savelink']."'    class='bewaardeItems'>".$cart[PRODUCTNAME][$i]['eventnaam']."</a></td>"."\n";
  $strHTML .= "</tr>"."\n";
  if ($cart[PRODUCTNAME][$i]['favSRC'] == "favJA" && $cart[PRODUCTNAME][$i]  ['eventnaam'] == "Blackout") {
        $imageSRC = 'favJA';
  }
  else {
        $imageSRC = 'favNEE';
  }
 }

 $strHTML .= "</table>"."\n";
 $strHTML .= "</div>"."\n";
};
?>
```

The above code works, I can mark multiple products as favorite, all unique names are displayed as text on the right side of the page, the image src is changed perfectly to `favJA` (the same star but with color, so the visitor knows it's marked). But, as soon as I click another product and mark this one as favorit, it changes the image src, as I want, but forgets the other products that are marked before. The list on the right contains all the unique names, it remembers all the products that are marked, but the image doesn't. The image only recognizes the last product. As soon as a new product is marked it unmarks all the other images.

What am I missing here? How can I keep the image marked regardless the number of products which are marked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've created a workaround. I've added a new `SESSION`value to the code, holding the name of the productpage and the value of the image.

```
<?php 
session_start();

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

 define("PRODUCTNAME", 1);
define("inURL", 1);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
   if (isset($_POST['productname']))
   {
      AddToCart();
   }
} 


function AddToCart()
{
   $cart = isset($_SESSION['cart']) ? $_SESSION['cart'] : '';
   $itemcount = isset($_SESSION['itemcount']) ? $_SESSION['itemcount'] : 0;
   $event = $_POST['productname'];
   $savelink = $_POST['url'];
   $longeventname = $_POST['longeventname'];
   $favIMGsrc = 'favJA';

   $cart[PRODUCTNAME][$itemcount] = array('eventnaam' => $event, 'savelink' =>     $savelink);
   $itemcount = $itemcount + 1;

   $_SESSION['cart'] = $cart;
   $_SESSION['event_url_'.$longeventname] = $favIMGsrc;
   $_SESSION['itemcount'] = $itemcount;
   header('Location: ' . $_POST['url']);
exit;
} 
?>
```

On the product page, simply call the `session` and let php compare it's value. If the value matches YES, the `img src` is set to YES. If the value returns a NO, the `img src` is set to NO.

```
<?php 
session_start();

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

define("PRODUCTNAME", 1);

$cart = isset($_SESSION['cart']) ? $_SESSION['cart'] : '';
$eventURL = isset($_SESSION['event_url_blackout']) ? $_SESSION['event_url_blackout'] : '';
$itemcount = isset($_SESSION['itemcount']) ? $_SESSION['itemcount'] : 0;
$strHTML = "";

if ($itemcount == 0)
{
   $strHTML = "<font class='bewaardeItems'>U heeft nog geen evenementen aangeklikt.    </font>";
   $imageSRC = 'favNEE';
}
else
{
   $strHTML = "<div style=\"overflow:auto; height=358px;\">"."\n";
   $strHTML .= "<table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"3\" cellspacing=\"2\"     width=\"100%\">"."\n";

   for ($i=0; $i<$itemcount; $i++)
   {
      $strHTML .= "<tr>"."\n";
      $strHTML .= "<td><a href='".$cart[PRODUCTNAME][$i]['savelink']."'     class='bewaardeItems'>".$cart[PRODUCTNAME][$i]['eventnaam']."</a></td>"."\n";
      $strHTML .= "</tr>"."\n";
   }

   $strHTML .= "</table>"."\n";
   $strHTML .= "</div>"."\n";
};

if ($eventURL == "favJA"){
    $imageSRC = 'favJA';
} else {
            $imageSRC = 'favNEE';
      }
?>
```

That solved the problem!